# How to declare objects for nested form in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, has-one

I'm approaching my 2nd week of using rails, and have almost gotten the structure of my app complete (I think/hope). I'm building a staff website for a charity, which as part of their work collects and wipes computers (before sending them to African schools!).

I've set up my app to have staff, computer, and wipe models / classes, and nested the form for the wiping details inside the form for the computer details. When I create a new computer, I can enter the wiping details without a problem, and if I edit the wiping details of an existing computer **that already has wiping details** it also works great. But when I go to add wiping details to an existing computer **without wiping details** I get the following error:

```
undefined method `staff=' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #49):
```

How do I correctly set computer.wipe.staff = to the current user. Note that to edit or submit wiping details a user must be logged in.

My models are as follows (ignoring irrelevant validations, etc):

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wipes
  before_save { self.staff_email = staff_email.downcase }
  validates :staff_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 50}
  has_secure_password
end

class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :wipe, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :wipe
end

class Wipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :computer#, dependent: destroy
  belongs_to :staff
  validates :staff_id, presence: true
 #validates :computer_id, presence: true
  validates :action_taken, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 250 }
end
```

My computer controller is as follows:

```
class ComputersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_computer, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
  before_action :require_user, except: [:new, :create]

  layout :new_layout, only: [:new, :update]

  def new
    @computer = Computer.new
    @computer.build_wipe
  end

  def create
    @computer = Computer.new(computer_params)
    if logged_in?
      @computer.wipe.staff = current_user
    end
    if @computer.save
      flash[:success] = "You're computer's details have been submitted successfully!"
      redirect_to computers_path
    else
      render :new, layout: new_layout
    end
  end

  def edit
    unless @computer.wipe
      @computer.build_wipe
    end
  end

  def update
    @computer.wipe.staff = current_user #This is the line not working, yet seems to work correctly in the create action
    if @computer.update(computer_params)
      flash[:success] = "The computer's details have been updated successfully!"
      redirect_to computer_path(@computer)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

    #Whitelisting variables
    def computer_params
      params.require(:computer).permit(:manufacturer, :computer_type, :specification, :donor, :model_no, :serial_no, :product_key, :turingtrack, :picture, wipe_attributes: [:id, :action_taken, :staff_id])
    end

    def set_computer
      @computer = Computer.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

My view is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="well col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <%= form_for(@computer, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :manufacturer %>
      <%= f.text_field :manufacturer, :placeholder => "Toshiba" %>
      <%= f.label :computer_type, "Computer Type" %>
      <%= f.text_field :computer_type, :placeholder => "Laptop"%>

      <% if logged_in? %>
        <br><strong>Wiping Details:<br><br></strong>
        <%= f.fields_for :wipe do |wipe_form| %>
          <%= wipe_form.label :action_taken %>
          <%= wipe_form.text_field :action_taken %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit(@computer.new_record? ? "Submit Details" : "Submit Edited Details", class: "btn btn-success") %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

Furthermore, currently I am not setting the `computer_id` when using the nested wipe form inside the computer form, it seems to automatically assign it (e.g. If I created a new computer/edit one and enter the wiping details, the `computer_id` for that wipe is that of the computer also created/edited). Is this assumption correct? I read somewhere about not being able to validate parent's foreign keys, but it was too brief to really understand. It throws an error when I try to validate `computer_id` in the wipes model, hence the validation being commented out. Why is this, and is it okay practice to leave it like this?

Thank you everyone

Comment: your `@computer.wipe` is not set. i.e. It is `nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved my problem, though I can't quite understand why it works. 
I built a wipe object in both the edit and update actions. The first one creates the input field in the form, the second is the instance used when assigning the staff member. Note that when I check in the console to see whether two wipe objects have been created, only a single one has, as required.

```
def edit
  unless @computer.wipe
    @computer.build_wipe
  end
end

def update
  if @computer.wipe 
  else
    @computer.build_wipe
  end
  @computer.wipe.staff = current_user
  if @computer.update(computer_params)
    flash[:success] = "The computer's details have been updated successfully!"
    redirect_to computer_path(@computer)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error:

```
    undefined method `staff=' for nil:NilClass.
```

this shows that *@computer.wipe* is nil. So while your *set_computer* method is correctly finding a computer based on the provided id, that *@computer* has no associated *wipe*.

*Edit:* This is likely related to a problem in your *build_wipe* method not correctly settings the wipe.

Comment: Hey @Andrew, thanks for the suggestion. I realised that my `@computer.wipe` is `nil` but I can't seem to work out why. According to the API docs, `build_wipe` should be used for `has_one` relationships such as mine instead of `wipe.build` for `has_many`. Furthermore, the same code seems to successfully generate an instance for the create action. Without the `build_wipe`, my form doesn't even generate the box to input anything. Any ideas as to my next step for debugging? Thanks

Comment: I've not come across the build_wipe method. Why not just assign a Wipe object to @computer? For example @computer.wipe = Wipe.new

Comment: When setting `@computer.wipe = Wipe.new` in my edit action, I get the following error when loading the edit view: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved in ComputersController#edit`, `Failed to save the new associated wipe.`